# Making a structure visible in both library and application - C

Tags: c, struct, .lib

I wanted to know how to make a structure visible in both - inside a library & in a external header. let me try to explain in the following code

I have a struct :

```
typedef struct{
int a;
int b;
}strt_1;
```

i want to create an instance of the same in the application and pass it to a library function and later update a & b variables inside, hence

application

```
int main()
{
    strt_1 a;
    foo(&a);
}
```

inside the library:

```
   int foo(strt_1 *a)
   {
      a->b = 0;
      a->a = 1;
   }
```

problem: 
if I create the definition of the struct in the library, when I retype the same in application, it shows as a redifinition(obviously). but if I type it in application, I wont be able to compile it as it says definition missing, Soo, how do I show the contents of the Struct to the external 3rd party library user, and also make it visible to the library compiler?

Comment: have you tried header files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should put the structure and the `typedef` in a header file that comes with the library. Both the library and the applications using the library uses this header file. Structures and typedefs defined in header file do *not* cause multiple definition errors, only defining *global variables* or *functions* in both will do that.

Also, functions in the library should be prototyped in the header files of your library as well.

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution is already used in the standard includes.

You can try to encapsulate it with an #ifdef.

Something like

--- Header file ---

```
#ifndef LIBRARYHEADERFILE_INCLUDED
#define LIBRARYHEADERFILE_INCLUDED

typedef struct{
int a;
int b;
}strt_1;

int foo(strt_1 *a);
#endif
```

--- End header file ---

Then, on your main program and library, you #include the header file. 
And that's it. Both your new type and the function are now visible in every place, without fear of redefinition  errors.

Comment: hmmm.. so, create a separate header for the structure and include it?

Comment: Create a header file, which is part of your library. And in this file, add this structure. What he means by using "#ifdef", is to avoid multiple definition. If ever, you have to use this header file in multiple source code files for your application.

Answer (score 1):

Put the `typedef` in a `MyLibrary.h` header file.  Then `#include "MyLibrary"` in both your library source file, and the external code using the binary version of the library.

Answer (score 1):

define structure in header file and include that header in c file before using structure.